# What is good way to limit the amount of comments shown to a user until they choose to view all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Currently I have an each loop in the template for where the comments are display. Say a user has 50 comments to a micropost they have posted. A long list showing 50 comments will be displayed.

To save space on the page I've decided I'd like to limit comments shown to 2-3 per micropost. If a user wishes to view more they can click "view more" or "view all". I'm wondering how a server would cope if there were like 10,000 comments and a user clicked "view all" which is why I may choose to implement "view more" then have like 50 more comments shown"

**Anyway I'd like to know a good way to limit the amount of comments shown to a user until they choose to view all?**

If I go the jquery/js route and make it so only the 2-3 most recent messages are shown the others would have still been loaded back end wouldn't they so wouldn't a better option be to control this in ruby on rails some how?

I'd really like some nice solutions/info on the best way  to do this.

Any further info you need I'd be happy to provide.

Thanks
Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like Facebook:

- Show only 2/3 comments. Load only 2/3 comments from the backend.
- When the users clicks "Show more", it shows 50 more. It loads them through AJAX. So on the backend you only get a request like "GET 50 comments EXCEPT the three firsts".
- Another "Show more" link is shown. It will load 50 other comments except the 53 firsts.

On Facebook, you can't load more than 50 comments at once. I think you should do the same.

Comment: This seems straight forward. I like! More comments are loaded only when they're needed or if I wanted I could load all? I've been looking closely at facebook and google+. Google+ seems to load all comments but I wonder how server friendly that would be when loaded say 10,000 users load say 2000 comments.

Comment: A lot less server friendly than only 50 comments, that's for sure! :-) You can also implement the "Show all" button, but would it be really worth it? Why not ditch it for now and use it eventually later if the users are asking for it? Implement it wouldn't be very long.

Answer (score 0):

The clean way is to implement pagination for comments.

Comment: I originally thought to use pagination also using will_paginate but if I was to set per_page to 2, each time I load more only 2 more results will show each time.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there's a simple `belongs_to` and `has_many` relationship between `Post` and `Comment`. I normally will do:

routes:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

model: set a default page size:

```
class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post

  DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE = 25
end
```

controller:

```
class CommentsController
  def index
    post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    offset = params[:offset] || 0
    limit = params[:limit] || Comment::DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE
    @comments = post.comments.offset(offset).limit(limit)

    respond_to do |format|
      #respond as you like
    end
  end

  # more actions...
end
```

view, a load more link something like, to load the comments via ajax:

```
<%= link_to "load more comments", post_comments_path(@post, :format => 'js'), :method => :get, :remote=>true id='load-more-comments' %>
```

and you also would like to bind the offset to the ajax post:

```
$ ->
  $('#load-more-comments').on 'ajax:before', (event) ->
    el = $(this)
    offset = #count your offset, I often do by counting the <li>s already in the <ul>
    el.data 'params', "offset=#{offset}"
    # you could also pass the limit: el.data 'params', "offset=#{offset}&limit=#{some limit}"
  .on 'ajax:complete', (event, xhr, status) ->
    el = $(this)
    el.removeData 'params' # remember to remove this.
```

I am also interested in what's the better way to do this. Looking forward to the answers and critics. :)

Comment: What do you think about showing only 2 comments first off then loaded the rest through ajax when needed?

Comment: I think I couldn't say it. I intend to implement it like you said right now, and observe the user behavior. If they intends to look deep  into the comments, then I would offer more comments for first off, and vice versa. I saw you asked for server friendly, I also think it depends, if you limit the page size, you will have more requests/db calls if the user really dig into the comments. So I would say it depends on the behavior, and I would go for the best user experienced one(not the server friendly) and test it and do optimizations later on. I don't know if this answers your question.