# How do I implement a show all comments feature in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm implementing show/hide feature for users comments.

Discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10174194/439688

My aim was to:
1. Limit the default shown comments to 2.
2. Have a span with text that states the number of total comments for that particular micropost and when clicked by a user have it expand and show all comments for that micropost. I would be using Jquery/Ajax to hide, show, prepend etc.

The first change was to limit the amount of comments shown to the user and I achieved this by creating a method in my helper called "comments" and here I pass in the id of the micropost the comment belongs to.

```
  def get_comments(micropost_id)
       Comment.limit(2).order("created_at DESC").where(:micropost_id => micropost_id)
  end
```

Now the each loop that loops through each comment will only show the 2 most recent comments.

```
  <<% @microposts.each do |m| %>
    <% if m.poster_id.nil? %>
       <div class="postHolder">
        <nav class="micropostOptions">
         <ul class="postMenu">
           <li class="deletePost"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Delete post"), m, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :title => m.content, :class => "message_delete", :remote => true %>
           </li>
           <li class="disableCommenting"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Pause commenting"), "2" %></li>
           <li class="blockCommenter"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Block commenter"), "3" %></li>
           <li class="openInNewWindow"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Open in new window"), "4" %></li>
           <li class="reportAbuse"><%= link_to content_tag(:span, "Report abuse"), "5" %></li>
         </ul>  
       </nav>


                <%= link_to image_tag(default_photo_for_current_user, :class => "poster_photo"), current_users_username %>

<div class="post_content">
    <div class="post_container">

        <div class="mainUserNameFontStyle"><%= link_to current_users_username.capitalize, current_users_username %> - <div class="post_time"> <%= time_ago_in_words(m.created_at) %> ago.</div> 
        </div>  
                  <%=  simple_format h(m.content) %> </div>
            <div class="commentsCount">
                <%= content_tag :span, pluralize(m.comments.count, 'comment'), :class => "view_all_comments" if m.comments.any? %>
            </div>
                        <% if m.comments.any? %>

                   <% comments(m.id).each do |comment| %>

                    <div class="comment_container">

                        <%= link_to image_tag(default_photo_for_commenter(comment), :class => "commenter_photo"), commenter(comment.user_id).username %>

                        <div class="commenter_content"> <div class="userNameFontStyle"><%= link_to commenter(comment.user_id).username.capitalize, commenter(comment.user_id).username %> - <%=  simple_format h(comment.content) %> </div>
                    </div><div class="comment_post_time"> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago. </div>


                   </div>


                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>


                <% if logged_in? %>
                <%= form_for @comment, :remote => true do |f| %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
                <%= f.hidden_field :micropost_id, :value => m.id %>
                <%= f.text_area :content, :placeholder => 'Post a comment...', :class => "comment_box", :rows => 0, :columns => 0 %>

        <div class="commentButtons">         
          <%= f.submit 'Post it', :class => "commentButton", :disable_with => "Post it" %>
           <div class="cancelButton"> Cancel </div>
        </div>   
                <% end %>

                <% end %>
    </div>


</div>
```

From here this is where it gets confusing for me. I got slightly further using link_to but then decided I'd prefer not to have the url to the comments count show in the browser status bar. This is why I switched to using span.. but now it's not quite easy to do what I wish to do as I can't use the link_to/remote => true now.

**How do I make it so when a user clicks the comment count span an ajax call is made pointing to:**

```
  def load_comments

  @load_comments = Comment.where(:micropost_id => params[:id])   
    respond_to do |format|
    format.js   { render :load_comments } 
    end

  end
```

I thought about putting a click function in users.js but how would I pass the params of the micropost that is in the each loop in the code above into users.js? I don't think it's possible.

All my comment posting is done via ajax but because I used forms for these it was so much easier for me to just add remote => true and create some js templates and do something on success of ajax post.

Not sure if I'm even going about this the right way. I'd appreciate some help/advice from more experienced rails programmers.

Kind regards

Comment: Why do you care about the link being shown in the status bar? Most users can't even find the location edit box to type a url so they just google for the url.

Comment: why not take your comments view inside a partial? then on click event of span, you can call ajax function which will update the entire partial(showing all the comments). also you can pass locals to partials. i have done a similar kind of thing. but not exactly as yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Rails partial**

#Display all the comments based on local passed to this partial

# Initially pass limit as 2(or whatever you want). then on click of span pass limit as nil. then you can check if limit is nil you can query the model without limit specifier.

```
<% @comments = Comment.custom_find(@your_params) %>
<% @comments.each do |comment|  %>
<%= comment.title %>
<% end %>
```

**javascript/jquery**

```
function load_all_comments(id)
{
   new Ajax.Updater('show_comments',
      '<%=url_for(:controller => "your_controller", :action => "your_action")%>', {
       parameters: {'id':id },
       method:     'get',
       onSuccess: function(request){
       div_comments = document.getElementById("partial_comments_list");
       div_comments.innerHTML = request.responseText;

      }
   });
} // you can call this js function on span click. use jquery if you want.
```

**Controller:**

Then inside your_action of your_controller, dont forget to render the partial

```
   render :partial => "show_comments", :layout => false
```

Edit:

```
you can even pass locals to your partial

 render :partial => "show_comments", :locals => {:post => @post}
```

Using this every time your partial view will get updated, on the basis of locals you pass.

of course this is just an example not a complete code/solution.

There may be better ways. but this worked fine for me.

Comment: Using partials was how I got my micropost posting and comments posted to the page successfully using ajax. It worked fine.. I was just confused with how I would use <%= %> inside my users.js..  Is that where your js code above goes into? A js file inside your assets or is it in one of your view folders?

Comment: well there can be multiple places to put js. but in may case i had put them in index.html.erb(where my span tag was) or in the file inside which I would render the partial. you can consider rjs files to put javascript code.

Comment: The first part I've done. I'm passing m.comments (micropost.comments) into my my partial "_show_all_comments". Should this be hidden by default? This way is slightly different from yours because I can access comments through each micropost "micropost.comments".. The problem is that this is showing the comments by default now. I was thinking to use css to hide then show on click of span but then how can I filter so that all comments are shown except the 2 most recent. This way when I prepend the partial into the page it will push down the 2 most recent comments.

Comment: Also this would also mean "all comments" are only loaded when the span is clicked.. seeing as the partials div is hidden hidden by default until click. I hope I'm correct.

Comment: partial will be called two times(passing different args both the time). FIRST partial will be called from your main page(i.e. the page in which partial needs to get rendered). in this case pass limit = 2. while in SECOND case when you click on span(you can pass limit = 100) or whatever

Comment: "all comments" need not be loaded until user presses the span element. when span element is clicked, you can pass parameter or locals saying that limit = 100 or limit = nil. then put a condition to check if limit is nil then query without the limit specifier.

Comment: yep just checked and even if it's hidden by css the partial is stil rendered. I now understand why you're letting ajax call the partial instead. This way you don't need to place it in your view and only insert it when a user clicks span. I just need to figure out where to put the js now.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just output all of the comments and hide the ones you don't want to show first. `<div class="hidden_comments" style="display:none;"> a comment </div>`

Then just have some javascript to show them when the span is clicked?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#span_id").click(function() {
      $('.hidden_comments').show();
});
</script>
```

This works great if you do not don't have a ton of comments.

---

If you really want to do it your way, I have done it before but it gets messy.

Put this in your application.js

```
$('.comment_span').live('click', function () {
    $.get(this.data_url, null, update_row, 'json');
    return false;
  });
```

Your span would look like this:

```
<span class="comment_span" data_url="http://website.com/resource/more_comments">
  show all comments
</span>
```

This example returns the data as json, so I used the update_row function to update replace the comments data.

```
 function update_row(data, status) {
    $("#comments-table").append(data.html);
  };
```

Here is what my controller looked like:

```
  def more_comments
    @comments = Comments.all

    if @comments
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js {
                render :json => { 
                  :html => render_to_string(:partial => "comments"),
                  }.to_json
              }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: I initially thought of that as an option but as you made obvious when you start to get a several comments for each micropost it can become a problem. I understand exactly what you mean when you stated it gets messy. When things become that way I become confused and slow down tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this via your index action.
Pass a param to it to determine if you want to show all comments or just the current set (I'd use will_paginate to handle this.
Haven't looked too deep into your code as I'm on my phone right now, but something like this:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    If params[:show_all] == "true"
      @comments = Comment.all
    else
      @comments = Comment.where(foo: bar).paginate(per_page: 2, page: params[:page])
    end
  end
```

Then you have it respond to JavaScript and send the page param with your Ajax request